# How to list available SMB Servers on LAN without Auth (Java)

Tags: java, smb, jcifs

I'm aware of [JCIFS](https://jcifs.samba.org/) library but `SmbFile` doesn't work without `NTLM Authentication` if you were to `List` all directories available to access at `smb://` root of the network.

And having to enter credentials even before the server could be found (so that `Auth` token could be made) doesn't seem to be a good UX.

What is the workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Found out by trial and error that

`SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile("smb://", new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(null, null, null));`

works when you're trying to access anything upto `smb://workgroup/servername` without login credentials.

Comment: I tried with this code: `SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile("smb://", new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(null, null, null));
  System.out.println(smbFile.list());`. and get `jcifs.smb.SmbException: Failed to connect to server` why?